# dots indicator not changing position of dot, flutter

Tags: flutter, indexing, indicator

I have used the following code for my three walkthrough pages, when I click dot it navigates to the page but not the position(index) of the dot indicator. After navigation the dot position comes back to the first dot.

```
final _totalDots = 3;

  double _currentPosition = 0.0;

  double _validPosition(double position) {
    if (position >= _totalDots) return 0;
    if (position < 0) return _totalDots - 1.0;
    return position;
  }

  void _updatePosition(double position) {
    setState(() => _currentPosition = _validPosition(position));
  }

  _ontap(double pos) {
    if (pos == 0) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const WalkThroughPageOne()));
      });
      _currentPosition = 0;
    } else if (pos == 1) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const WalkThroughPageTwo()));
      });
      _currentPosition = 1;
    } else if (pos == 2) {
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const WalkThroughPageThree()));
      });
      _currentPosition = 2;
    }
  }
```

The following is the build method. How can use the pageview controller here and change the index of the dot indicator on-tap and swipe on screen as well.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DotsIndicator(
      onTap: (pos) {
        _ontap(pos);
        setState(() {
          _updatePosition(pos);
        });
      },
      dotsCount: _totalDots,
      position: _currentPosition,
      decorator: DotsDecorator(
        size: const Size.square(8.0),
        activeColor: Colors.teal[700],
        activeSize: const Size(25.0, 8.0),
        activeShape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And here is my main method. Help me with this Please!

```
home: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, authsnapshot) {
          if (authsnapshot.hasData) {
            return const QazaNaPage();
          }
          return const WalkThroughPageOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm seeing from your code you are using the setState() in a wrong way, in Flutter set state is used to change the current state of your application, ie, you change a property, and call set state, the UI is then rebuilt with the new information.

For example, imagine that you want to change the state of a button from selected to unselected you have to change the selected property inside the setState (or just before it) like in this example:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        selected = true;
      });
    }, child: Text(selected ? "SELECTED" : "UNSELECTED"));
  }
}
```

or you can check the interactive Dartpad here: https://dartpad.dev/?id=8891fbf9635f005e1e10e140a6f13302

You are navigating the user away, but your state change happens after the setState, so it won't be updated properly, you should try the opposite: put the _currentPosition inside the setState() and the navigation outside

```
_ontap(double pos) {
  if (pos == 0) {
    setState(() {
      _currentPosition = 0;
    });
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const WalkThroughPageOne()));
  }
  //Other pages logic
}
```